# How to create a list of structured scalars in numba?

Tags: python, numpy, numba, structured-array

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

dt = np.dtype([('x', np.float64), ('y', np.float64)])

@njit
def f():
#    a = np.zeros(2, dtype=dt)         # this works
#    return a['x']
    b = np.array((0.5, 1.5), dtype=dt)    # this doesn't
#    return b['x']
f()
```

The error message is

```
NotImplementedError: Cannot cast float64 to Record(x[type=float64;offset=0],y[type=float64;offset=8];16;False): %".69" = phi double [%".70", %"switch.0"], [%".72", %"switch.1"]
```

Without @jit it works fine.

What I'm really trying to acheive is to create a List of custom dtype scalars. I've tried the following alternatives:

- numpy array is not a good fit as the number of elements is not known in advance,
- a list of numpy vectors requires too much of numeric indexing, something I'm trying to avoid
- a list of dicts (supposedly) takes too much memory
- a numpy array of jitted classes is too slow compared to any of the other variants listed above.

**Update:**
The furthest point I could get so far is:

```
dt = np.dtype([('x', np.float64), ('y', np.float64)])
@nb.njit
def f():
    a = np.array((0.5, 1.5))
    b = a.view(dt)
    return b.x
f()

array([0.5])
```

but it is not a scalar, it is a 1-sized array (with or without @jit).

**Update2:**

Recfunctions are not covered with numba as yet.

```
from numpy.lib import recfunctions
from numba import njit
dt = np.dtype([('x', np.float64), ('y', np.float64)])
@njit
def f():
    a = np.array((1,2))
    b = recfunctions.unstructured_to_structured(a, dt)
    return b['x']
f()

Unknown attribute 'unstructured_to_structured' of type 
Module(<module 'numpy.lib.recfunctions'
```

Comment: Does `np.array([(0.5, 1.5)],  dtype=dt)` work?

Comment: @hpaulj unfortunately, not. I've updated the answer with what I've managed to reach so far.

Comment: Even without `numba` your `f` would be size 1.  Using `view` to convert unstructured  to structured requires shape adjustment.  `np.lib.recfuctions.unstructured_to_structured` does a cleaner conversion.

Comment: @hpaulj yes, but so would `np.array([(0.5, 1.5)], dtype=dt)` shape be. I just gave it as the closest alternative to this line I've came up with. As for `unstructured_to_structured` - I've tried it already, numba isn't aware of it. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evidently `numba` has not fully implemented the `numpy` structured array functionality.  The error indicate that it has problems assigning values from a tuple to a defined array.

After playing around a bit, I found that this works:

```
In [399]: dt = np.dtype([('x', np.float64),('y', np.float64)])                  
In [400]: @numba.njit 
     ...: def nf(vals, dt): 
     ...:     b = np.zeros((), dtype=dt) 
     ...:     b['x'][...] = vals[0] 
     ...:     b['y'][...] = vals[1] 
     ...:     return b 
     ...:                                                                       
In [401]: nf((.5,1.5),dt)                                                       
Out[401]: array((0.5, 1.5), dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8')])
```

Or to make a 1d array:

```
In [405]: @numba.njit 
     ...: def nf1(n, x, y , dt): 
     ...:     b = np.zeros(n, dtype=dt) 
     ...:     b['x'][...] = x 
     ...:     b['y'][...] = y 
     ...:     return b 
     ...:                                                                       
In [406]: nf1(3, np.arange(3), np.ones(3), dt)                                  
Out[406]: array([(0., 1.), (1., 1.), (2., 1.)], dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8')])
```

Comment: Works like a charm! That's exactly what I was looking for and I must admit I would've hardly found this syntax in the nearest future.